# Exporting valgrind(memcheck) from Qt Creator 4.0.2

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, valgrind

I'm running valgrind on my project and get some results. Is there a way to save these results to a file? I see only the small folder icon for loading xml, is there any equivalent for saving? Thanks

[image: results screenshot]

Comment: Why don't you just run valgrind from the terminal and get these results to a file using stdout `>` operator of bash?

Comment: Of course I can, but I ran this for two days (well, valgrind is slow...) and don't want to wait another two.

Comment: I remember trying that out, but can't remember for sure. A couple leads: right clicking in the memcheck or checking the build output folder for the log file might provide the answer. I cannot do the test here unfortunately.